# How to run shell script array in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, dash-shell

I am learning shell script language. I write and run the code using Ubuntu terminal.I have declare an array with value like below..

```
arr=(1 2 3)
echo $(arr[0])
echo $(arr[1])
echo $(arr[2])
```

The above code doesn't run.Whenever I run using the terminal,I face error like below..

```
./a.sh: line 2: arr[0]: command not found
./a.sh: line 3: arr[1]: command not found
./a.sh: line 4: arr[2]: command not found
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Note: arrays won't work in (da)sh, however the error format suggests you did use bash here.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `$(...)` is for executing sub-shell commands.

Use syntax `${...}` to read variable content. So:

```bash
arr=(1 2 3)
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
echo ${arr[2]}
```